# Arduino + CO2 + humidity + noise + temperature sensors on one board

Tags: sensors

I'm looking for an Arduino board that include this sensors out of the box:

- CO<sub>2</sub>
- Humidity
- Noise
- Temperature

I've found here [Using the Waspmote Sensor Board](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/269/using-the-waspmote-sensor-board) something that could be enough, but I'm searching for more options.

I did a lot of searches on the Internet without good results.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

For humidity and temperature you can plug the DHT11 or DHT22 to your arduino. DHT11 is cheaper but you'll get a more precise value with DHT22.

For noise you have ready made PCB like these : [here](http://www.ebay.com/sch/items/?_nkw=arduino%20sound%20sensor&_sacat=&_ex_kw=&_mPrRngCbx=1&_udlo=&_udhi=&_sop=12&_fpos=&_fspt=1&_sadis=&LH_CAds=&rmvSB=true)
You'll only have to plug it to GND, 5V and analog input.

For CO2 this is more complicate. There is a cheap but very unprecise option, using a MQ135 sensor, here is a tutorial: [here](https://hackaday.io/project/3475-sniffing-trinket/log/12363-mq135-arduino-library)
Otherwise there are better sensors like the [K30](http://www.co2meter.com/products/k-30-co2-sensor-module) but they are much more expensive.